# Socket programming android

Tags: android, sockets

I'm working with client server architecture. I need to send my local ip address to server.

I accomplish it by using this code below:

```
Socket soc = new Socket(ipaddress,port)
```

But the problem is , my local ip address and the address which obtained with above code are different.

How to solve this difficulty???
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `new Socket(...)` doesn't obtain an IP address, it creates an outbound connection. In any case you need to send it why? The server can get it from the accepted socket, as soon as your client connects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Socket mSocket = new Socket(hostAddress, port)
```

hostAddress is the server address(remote host address).
  port is the port number to perform IO operations.

you can send the address manually to the server :-

```
try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("hostIpAddress");
            Socket mSocket = new Socket(addr,8080);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    mSocket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new
                    DataInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(getIpAddress());
            String sereverMesssage = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            if(sereverMesssage!=null && sereverMesssage.equals("Success")){
                Log.i("Socket","Local Ip Address received by server");
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
        return ip;
    }
```

Comment: `serverMessage` cannot be null. You assume the peer uses `readUTF()`.